# Co-ordinate transformation of diffusion and heat equation PDE for dimensionless $r$ (1D spherical case)

Tags: temperature, diffusion

I'm trying to simulate the drying of a particle using the heat and diffusion equations for a 1D spherical case
$$ Heat: \frac {\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{\alpha}{r^2}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\right)\right] $$

$$ Diffusion: \frac {\partial X}{\partial t} = \frac{D}{r^2}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial X}{\partial r}\right)\right] $$

subject to the initial conditions

$$T(r,t) = T_0 \ at \ t=0$$
$$X(r,t) = X_0 \ at \ t=0 $$

with boundary conditions for temperature

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial r} = 0 \ at \ r=0 $$
$$-k\frac{\partial T}{\partial r} = h(T_R - T_{inf}) \ at  \ r=R $$
and moisture
$$ \frac{\partial X}{\partial r} = 0 \ at \ r=0 $$
$$-D\frac{\partial X}{\partial r} = h_m(X_e - X_r) $$

I've successfully implemented the above equations into a MatLab model  that has reasonable accuracy.

However I want to model the effect of shrinkage. Therefore I need to introduce a dimensionless radius $r' = \frac{r}{R(t)}  $ and make the corresponding coordinate transformation in my equations

The problem being I haven't done this kind of math in years. Would anyone be able to help me to describe how to do coordinate transformation.

Comment: You could write $r = R(t)r'$ and substitute that into all your equations (and boundary or initial conditions), unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @jsborne for my current model I need to ensure that the radius I am using is dimensionless so that my mesh is always on [0,1]. 

I.e. so the coordinate for r at each time t runs between r = 0 and r = R(t)
if this is normalized as r' = r/R(t), the r' coordinate runs between r' = 0/R(t) = 0 and r' = R(t)/R(t) = 1